What is the significance of $\langle\partial_xF_x,\partial_yF_y,\partial_zF_z\rangle$?
Given a vector field $F=\langle F_x,F_y,F_z\rangle,$ does the vector $\langle\partial_xF_x,\partial_yF_y,\partial_zF_z\rangle$ have any significance? I tried expressing it as some product of the vector with a matrix and I get
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\partial_x&0&0\\
0&\partial_y&0\\
0&0&\partial_z
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
F_x\\
F_y\\
F_z\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
which is the diagonal of the Jacobian, but I don't think this is very insightful.

Please avoid titles that consist of nothing but Mathjax, because they break some navigational shortcuts.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence

This quantity is basis-dependent, so its unlikely to have much geometric significance.

@Toffomat the divergence is a scalar quantity
